# PhpStorm - Choose which SASS-files to show autocomplete from first

Tags: phpstorm

I'm working on a project that has:

- Bootstrap
- FontAwesome
- It's own custom stylings

When I write something like this:

```scss
.some-el {
 font-size: $f     (and then wait)
}
```

Then it thinks for a second and then suggests something like this:

```scss
$focus [my variable]
$fa-font-display [implicitly imported from font-awesome]
$fa-font-path [implicitly imported from font-awesome]
$fa-css-prefix [implicitly imported from font-awesome]
$font_size_base [my variable - that I was looking for]
...
...
```

It gets better with time, since it remembers what I've used previously - so I guess this is something that would fix itself. But it would be awesome to be able to fix it myself right away.

This is just an example where FontAwesome-variable are a nuisance, but other times it's the Bootstrap-variables.

How can I define which SASS-variables that are suggested (and/or the order of the suggestions)?

---

### Solution attempts

- Googled a bunch.
- Looking through settings for 'Code Completion' and 'Code Style'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. The only way I can think of is excluding the folder where the `.css`/`.scss` files you don't like getting completion from are stored from indexing (**Mark directory as/excluded**).
Related feature request: [WEB-41257](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-41257)